# When should SecureZeroMemory() be used?

Tags: c++

I found some sample code that looks like:

```
addrinfo hints;
SecureZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
```

Is there a reason to use SecureZeroMemory() here? Why not just

```
addrinfo hints = {0};
```

Sample Code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: looks odd to me. I'd have said the function is for blanking values *after* using them (to prevent other processes seeing passwords, for example). So in this case I would have just used `memset` in C or relied on the zeroed-by-default behaviour of C++.

Comment: The documentation of `getaddrinfo` did say that four members of the `addrinfo` must be zero or the call will fail, but there's no obvious reason why `= {0};` won't work equally well. My guess is that for a code example, a `SecureZeroMemory` call is more self-explanatory than `= {0};`

Answer (score 9):

If (for example) the variable is not used anymore in the present scope (or in any other scenario where the compiler proves it doesn't change the internal coherence the program), the compiler could optimize away the zeroing statement. For security-critical memory, this could compromise the security of the application when it comes to external processes examining the memory of yours. `SecureZeroMemory` is written so that it does not get optimized away.

I can't tell for sure why this particular code snippet chooses that function over other methods of zeroing a memory range. It could be a misunderstanding of its purpose by the code's author or a misguided company policy.

Answer (score 6):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Use this function instead of `ZeroMemory` when you want to ensure that your data will be overwritten promptly, as some C++ compilers can optimize a call to `ZeroMemory` by removing it entirely.

Additionally a simple assignment, w/o a barrier, may be cached by hardware and not make it to the RAM for long time. Or a local variable may be optimized away. SecureZeroMemory makes sure none of that happens.

As to why use for initializing `addrinfo`, a clearly non-security related concern, beats me.