# Is free/=NULL enough to clear memory, or should SecureZeroMemory be placed immediately before it?

Tags: c, free, securezeromemory

What's the best way to clear out this allocated memory?

1. Is free/=NULL all that's needed
2. Does SecureZeroMemory before doing a free/=NULL add to the security of the code?
3. Or, is adding SecureZeroMemory overkill?

Here's my code:

```
        DWORD tLen = 128;
        BYTE *pbData = (BYTE *)malloc(tLen);
        memcpy(pbData, chBuffer, tLen);

        // ...work done here...

        // Clear it
        SecureZeroMemory(pbData, tLen);
        free(pbData);pbData=NULL;
```

Thanks!

EDIT: This question is *not a duplicate* of the question some people have said it is. It is not asking *when* to use SecureZeroMemory, but the best practice when used with free/=NULL.

Comment: I would use `SecureZeroMemory` only if I was dealing with sensitive information in memory, in this case...

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18944026/when-should-securezeromemory-be-used) might help you

Comment: Thanks, but that question does not examine the free() functin *in conjunction with* SecureZeroMemory() - that question is only looking at SecureZeroMemory, which is different than what I'm asking.

Comment: What is "free/=NULL"? What do you mean by that? You flagged one of the comments here suggesting that this isn't a duplicate, but it's pretty clearly a duplicate to me. Free doesn't clear memory in any way, and setting a pointer to null does absolutely nothing. If you want to clear the memory, then you need to call SecureZeroMemory(), which is exactly what the answers to the proposed duplicate say.

Comment: "free/=NULL' is shorthand for "free(x);x=NULL;" Thanks, your reply just answered my original question and confirms that the other article simply explains SecureZeroMemory() which is not what I'm asking.

Comment: and the 'free()' function is not even mentioned in that other article...which is what I am asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what your program is doing. If someone else can look at a buffer of freed memory, is that a concern to you? If the memory contains bank account details, I'd say that it is. If it contains settings for a video game, maybe not (depending on how determined your users are to cheat).

Bit generally it doesn't do any harm to shred memory before freeing it.

Comment: "Bit generally it doesn't do any harm to shred memory before freeing it." Other than waste time. If it was worth doing a zero on every free, then the standard library would do it for you. In 99% of cases, this is not necessary.